# Flashing BIOS update on Dell XPS 13 (2015)

Tags: dell, flash, bios

I have been trying to flash my BIOS to upgrade it to version A05, as suggested to me by Dell (since my computer has some bugs that make it unusable).

I created a FreeDOS disk with Unetbootin, copied the file from Dell on there; `9343_BIOS_Rev_A05.exe` ; and when I boot the disk, the file doesn't seem to be on there.

I also read some people the image (I don't really have an image, but an exe file), in /boot/xxxx, but I use grub instead of sputnik's default.

I tried running the exe with wine to extract it, but it gives an error. Any ideas? I don't have a UEFI system.

Comment: Store the update binary on your EFI partition (/boot/efi) or on a USB flash drive, reboot, and choose BIOS Update in the F12 boot menu.  This is from the generally excelent Arch Wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_%282015%29#BIOS_updates. I have not tried it myself.

Comment: Because my systems is not UEFI, it's not a duplicate of the refered to question. After a long search and trial process, I've eventually managed to do it like this http://dorienherremans.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/dell-xps13-2015-updates-and-bios.html

Comment: Is it possible to invert or remove the "duplicate" tag? The answer given here is much better (at least for the Dell XPS 13) than for the question it is allegedly  a duplicate of.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Only UEFI system method :**

There is now an easier way to install BIOS update. Simply run :

```
wget http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER03172775M/1/9343_BIOS_Rev_A05.exe
sudo cp 9343_BIOS_Rev_A05.exe /boot/efi/
```

Boot in your computer BIOS (hit <kbd>F12</kbd> when Dell's logo is displayed) then select **Bios Flash Update** and the update will be installed.

---

Successfully tested on my XPS 13 (9343, 2015) with A05 update.

Successfully tested on XPS 13 (9350) with XPS_9350_1.3.3.exe, too.

(Inspired from [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(2015)#BIOS_updates))

Comment: I only have /boot/grub. Would that work too?

Comment: I see some explanation about it here;https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Flashing_BIOS_from_Linux But I am unsure wether an exe file could be used instead of an img?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the `/boot/efi` folder ? What is the output of the commands of my answer?

Comment: cd /boot  then ls gives /grub. I don't have the developer's version, but installed kubuntu myself.

Comment: cp 9343_BIOS_Rev_A05.exe /boot/efi/
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/boot/efi/’: Not a directory

Comment: Did you installed Kubuntu in EFI mode ?

Comment: You mean UEFI mode? I am not entirely sure I know what you mean. Can I check somewhere?  I use grub as a bootloader. Is there any way to switch?

Comment: oh, i did turn off uefi to be able to boot a usb. It's a bios option isn't it?

Comment: Aaah right then... That mean you installed Kubuntu in non-uefi mode (why have done that?). Sorry but I don't know how to install Bios update in this case...

Comment: @dorien: if freedos doesn't work, wine doesn't work, and UEFI isn't available to you, you should talk to Dell again, as the only other way is to get  a native Linux version...  I would try renaming the file to `BIOS-UPD.EXE` under freedos when you save it there.

Comment: Download the Windows BIOS 1.3.3 and install it performing described way above works for newer XPS13 (9350), too.

Comment: I can confirm this also works with the 9360 version (2016).

Comment: this totally worked for me - but i'm using debian 9.2. i wish i found this answer before the last 6 hours of trying to make a bootable windows usb to run the exe :/