# How to update BIOS of Dell XPS 13 9310 on Ubuntu?

Tags: updates, dell, update-manager, bios, xps

I tried this: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/pt-br/000131486/atualizar-o-bios-da-dell-em-um-ambiente-linux-ou-ubuntu on my Dell XPS 13 9310. I formatted the usb drive as FAT32 and copied the .exe file to it, but when I enter the bios update option it cannot find the usb drive. I tried many options, pressing F12 or F2 on boot, etc.

I also know that it can be updated through update manager, but I don't see a BIOS update in my software updater

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks, movin to /boot/efi worked. Don't know why it didn't by moving to usb drive

Comment: Newer Dell are supported by fwupd See: https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devices/com.dell.ueficfb08d7c.firmware  Others: https://fwupd.org/vendorlist & 
https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving the .exe bios update file to /boot/efi and then finding it through the BIOS updates worked.

Related: [Flashing BIOS update on Dell XPS 13 (2015)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676594/flashing-bios-update-on-dell-xps-13-2015)